# How do I create a scrollable div with CompositeView in Dart?

Tags: dart

i'm trying to use CompositeView from the ui_lib in Dart. I want to display stuff in a div that can be scrolled up and down. So far I have no luck and there isn't much sample with that.

Thanks in advance,
user864555

**Edit:**

I went futher. Now, I haave the scrollbar showing up, but the size of the content seen to be the size of the window. So, yes I can see swipe up and down and see more more stuff, but it bounce back to the original position which is at the beginning.

```
var v = new CompositeView('example', true, true, true, true);
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    v.addchild(new View.html("<div><h1>Some text</h1></div>"));
}
```

Comment: Could you add a code example of what you are doing and want to accomplish.

Comment: What ui_lib are you trying to use?

Comment: I was trying to use the one that is provided with Dart samples http://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fdart%2Fsamples%2Fui_lib

Comment: Ah, I believe that library is deprecated and unmaintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to make sure that the container of your content has the size of the window. To do that, you need to add some CSS:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is the important bit, you have to give your container div this:

```
.example {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```